# How can I keep the previewFrame image straight as preview display?

Tags: android, camera

I use  **setDisplayOrientation** method to make the camera display straight , but the data get from previewCallback is not straight. while looking up the Android API , I found this

> This does not affect the order of byte array passed in onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos. This method is not allowed to be called during preview.

So how can I keep the previewFrame image data straight as preview display.